# Problems Flying in Minecraft PE 1.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Has anybody else had problems being able to fly in creative mode and found a fix, never had a problem before, just a double tap and I was airborne, now I do the same and I can't move up or down after double tapping the jump, please help

Answer (score 0):

Check your screen, make sure the problem isn't in minecraft pe itself (the app)
Try to rotate the screen then double tap, or clear the cache, I don't really know an exact solution to that,so sorry if it doesn't work.